# How do I randomly generate a variable name?

Tags: python, list, variables

In python, I need to know how to randomly generate a variable name for a list, but I am unsure how to go about doing this.

Right now, I have something like this written.

```
name = random.randint(0,9)
name = [a,b,c,d]
```

I know this will just change the 'name' variable to be the list. 
What I want to do is get my randomly generated number to be assigned as a variable to the list. How do I do this?

I'm fairly new to python as well, so if there is a better way of doing this, I would be open to suggestions.

Comment: "_Assigned as a variable to the list_" - I'm not sure what you mean. You want the variable name for the list to be a random number?

Comment: We call this the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/347908).  What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: It might also help to read [ask]. There are some good tips there for asking technical questions effectively. This is 80% of getting a good answer.

Comment: Please supply what should be your expected output.

Comment: Do you mean the variable name ```name``` to be a random value or ```a,b,c,d``` to be random values ?

Comment: See [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Generate variables :

You can create variables from a list of strings with the following code, but I don't think this is common practice.

```
name = ['a','b','c','d']
values = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(len(name))]

for var_value, var_name in zip(values,name):
    locals()[var_name] = var_value

name = [a,d,c,b]

#[8, 8, 6, 4]
```

## Better to make a dictionary:

You can do what you want to by creating a dictionary.

```
names = ['a','b','c','d'] 
values = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(len(name))]

# make a list of tuples that become the dictionary  
names_and_values = []
    for var_value, var_name in zip(values,name):
    names_and_values.append((var_value, var_name))

# create a dictionary with defined vairables
names = {name: value for name, value in names_and_values}

#{1: 'c', 2: 'd', 3: 'a', 5: 'b'}
```